# How to make the transfer of a parameter to a method by a constant reference?

Tags: c++, oop

I need to pass a parameter to a method using a constant link.

In the line "bool operator == (const Rational x) const;" I put "&" in front of "x", but that doesn't help, what should I do?

```
class Rational {
private:
    int chislitel;
    int znum;
public:
    Rational(int chislitel, int znum);
    Rational();
    bool operator==(const Rational x) const;

    void Print();
};
```

.
.
.

```
bool Rational::operator==(const Rational x) const
{
    if (chislitel * x.znum == znum * x.chislitel)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

my solution -> error

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: What's the error? Because yes, you should use a const ref and not a const value.

Comment: Also, this should be `return chislitel * x.znum == znum * x.chislitel;`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/ReUhPM

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MatthieuBrucher!

```
 class Rational {
    private:
        int chislitel;
        int znum;
    public:
        Rational(int chislitel, int znum);
        Rational();
        bool operator==(const Rational& x) const;

        void Print();
    };

    bool Rational::operator==(const Rational& x) const
    {
        return chislitel * x.znum == znum * x.chislitel;
    }
```